# Display add user screen in Windows Server OOBE

Tags: windows, windows-server-2012, deployment, sysprep, waik

I am currently making system images for deployment to our production hardware. I am creating both 32-bit Windows Standard 8 Embedded and 64-bit Windows Server 2012 images. What I am trying to do is make the OOBE process as consistent as possible between the two OSes to minimize the amount of documentation that needs to be written for the engineers responsible for deploying these images.

The main thing that I want to be consistent is for the Server 2012 OOBE to include the "Add User" screen that the Win8 OOBE includes. Is there a way to do this using an unattended installation XML script?

Any advice would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this is not possible AFAIK. The server is a server OS, and is usually not used with local user accounts.

Comment: I had a feeling that might be the case. Thanks for the response.